# How do I update multiple records at a time from a subselect inPL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

I have a stored procedure which works but is horribly slow.

Basically what I would like to do is update a set of rows I get from a sub query in a single update command. The other caveat is that I want to return the rows I updated in the statement.

Right now I am using a loop to get a single row and update it, storing the result using returning into, which works but is really slow.

Suggestions?

Here is the current working version along with the schema creation statements.

```
CREATE TABLE "queued_message"
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  body json NOT NULL,
  status character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  queue character varying(150) NOT NULL,
  last_modified timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TYPE returned_message as (id bigint, body json, status character varying(50) , queue character varying(150), last_modified timestamp without time zone);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_next_notification_message_batch(desiredQueue character varying(150), numberOfItems integer) 
    RETURNS SETOF returned_message AS $$ 
    DECLARE result returned_message; messageCount integer := 1;
    BEGIN
    lock table queued_notification_message in exclusive mode;
    LOOP 
        update queued_notification_message
        set 
            status='IN_PROGRESS', last_modified=now()
        where
            id in (
            select
                id
            from
                queued_notification_message
            where
                status='SUBMITTED' and queue=desiredQueue
            limit 1
            )
        returning * into result;
        RETURN NEXT result; 
        messageCount := messageCount+1;
        EXIT WHEN messageCount > numberOfItems;
    END LOOP;   
END;$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for a writable common table expression (wCTE). It's PL/PgSQL, by the way; PostgreSQL doesn't support the Oracle procedural language PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to accelerate code, that will be same due unsupported LIMIT clause for UPDATE statement, maybe following example can be enough:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fx2(n integer)
 RETURNS SETOF oo
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
  return query update oo set a = b 
                 where b in (select b 
                                from oo
                               order by b 
                               limit n) 
                 returning *;
  return;
end;
$function$

postgres=# insert into oo select 1, i from generate_series(1,100) g(i);
INSERT 0 100
postgres=# select * from fx2(1);
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 1
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from fx2(4);
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 1
 2 | 2
 3 | 3
 4 | 4
(4 rows)

postgres=# select * from oo limit 10;
 a | b  
---+----
 1 |  5
 1 |  6
 1 |  7
 1 |  8
 1 |  9
 1 | 10
 1 | 11
 1 | 12
 1 | 13
 1 | 14
(10 rows)
```